# Join with more than one, specific one-to-many rows

Tags: django, django-models

I have to join one row from table Type1 with two rows from table Type2. There are example models of database:

```
class Type1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Type2(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(Type1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.IntegerField()
```

In SQL, query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.name, B.value, C.value 
FROM Type1 A, Type2 B, Type2 C 
WHERE B.foreign = C.foreign = A.id 
AND B.name = _VAR1_ AND C.name = _VAR2_
```

How to do that query using Django methods (not raw SQL!)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, and know very little SQL to understand the SQL code.

Interpretation 1 is you want a reverse relationship query and a Q object for the OR part. See 'lookups that span relationship' and 'Complex lookups with Q objects' in [this](http://Lookups%20that%20span%20relationships%C2%B6) page.

Ex.

```
Type1.objects.filter(Q(type2__name = '_VAR1_' | type2__name = '_VAR2_'))
```

This return all rows of model Type1 that has an associated Type2 row with value *VAR1* or *VAR2* for name.

Interpretation 2: you want to define the relationship.
Well, that's easier. You have a Type1 row and want to associate two other rows with this one.
Query the Type1 row and save it to a variable.

```
t1 = Type1.object.get(id = X)
```

Then create type2 objects using t1 object in the foreign key:

```
t2 = Type2(foreign = t1, name = 'whatever', value = 'value')
t2.save()
```

and the same for the other object

```
t3 = Type2(foreign = t1, name = 'whatever2', value = 'value2')
t3.save()
```

Let me know if I misinterpreted the question.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for response. I will describe my problem: for every <element Type1 x> there is only one <element Type2 y1 with foreign=x and name=_VAR1_> and only one <element Type2 y2 with foreign=x and name=_VAR2_>. I want to receive table (QuerySet) with information from all of them. It should have following columns (Elements?) - [x.name, y1.value, y2.value]

Comment: Something like Type2.objects.filter(type2__name=_VAR1_).values('name', 'type2__value') and Type2.objects.filter(type2__name=_VAR2_).values('name', 'type2__value') combined

Comment: So you know the <element Type1 x> beforehang right?   Make a query and save it to a variable:  t1 = Type1.objects.get(id = x). Next make a query on Type2 to return your two rows:  t2 = Type2.objects.filter(Q(foreignkey = t1, name = VAR1 | foreignkey = t1, name = VAR2) ).  If you have only two associations as you said, this will return a list with two rows you want.  Your final list will be  [t1.name, t2[0].value,t2[1].value].

Comment: I want to have set of that lists (or any other container). So [t1.name, t2[0].value,t2[1].value] not only for one t1, but for every element of Type1.

Comment: I think a for loop can solve this, right?  result = []   /n   for el in Type1.objects.all():  /n    t = Type2.objects.filter(Q(foreignkey = el, name = VAR1 | foreignkey = el, name = VAR2) )  /n  result.append([el.name, t[0].value,t[1].value]) .

Comment: Maybe there is a way to do this in a single query, but I'm not sure how because you need two different columns for Type2, and that requires some postprocessing. The concept of join in django is pretty simple:  if you have an object with foreign key, you can chain a reference to the keyed objecy. If you make a row from Type2 saved in t2 variable, you can make the 'join' to Type1 like:   t2.foreign.name.  The thing is t2.foreign gives you the entire Type1 object, not only the ID. To get Type1 row ID associated with t2 row you can do t2.foreign.id.